# Property 'xy' does not exist on type '{}'. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to setup a small project with react / typescript and have the following components:

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Styles from "./App.module.scss";
import TopBar from "./components/TopBar/TopBar";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fab } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { faUser } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper/Wrapper";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import NewTask from "./components/NewTask/NewTask";
import AllTasks from "./components/AllTasks/AllTasks";

const App: React.FC = (props) => {
  library.add(fab, faUser);
  return (
    <div className={Styles.App}>
      <Router>
        <TopBar></TopBar>
        <Wrapper>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard></Dashboard>}></Route>
            <Route path="/new-task" element={<NewTask></NewTask>}></Route>
            <Route path="/all-tasks" element={<AllTasks></AllTasks>}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Wrapper>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and a component NewTask.tsx:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";
import Styles from "./NewTask.module.scss";
import TextInputField from "../Globals/commonUI/Input/TextInputField/TextInputField";
import SelectGroup from "../Globals/commonUI/SelectGroup/SelectGroup";
import TextArea from "../Globals/commonUI/Input/TextArea/TextArea";
import Submit from "../Globals/commonUI/Submit/Submit";

interface Properties {
  taskName?: string;
  taskType?: string;
  taskPriority?: string;
  taskDescription?: string;
  taskStatus?: string;
  task?: any[];
}
const NewTask: React.FC<Properties> = () => {
  const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState("");
  const [task, setTask] = useState({
    taskName: "",
    taskType: "",
    taskPriority: "",
    taskDescription: "",
    taskStatus: "new",
  });

  const formSubmitHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<any>): void => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Check if one or more inputs have been left empty

    for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      if (event.target.form[i].value === "") {
        setErrMsg("Hey buddy, you've left one or more fields empty!");
        // console.log("ive done this: " + i + " times!");
        return;
      }
    }

    // Inputs have been validated, errMsg is All Fine
    setErrMsg("All Fine!");
    // console.dir(task.task)
    // Post Input Values to API-Endpoint
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(task.task),
    };
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/task-write", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ postId: data.id }));

    // console.dir(task.task);
    // Reset Inputs
    formResetHandler(event);
  };

  const formResetHandler = (event) => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      event.target.form[i].value = "";
    }
  };

  const inputsChangedHandler = (event) => {
    // console.log("INPUT CHANGED!");
    let target = event.target;
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value;

    setTask((prevState) => ({
      task: {
        ...prevState.task,
        [name]: value,
      },
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className={Styles.newtask}>
      <div className={Styles.newtask__heading}>
        <h1>New Task</h1>
        <span>Add New Tasks</span>
      </div>
      <div className={Styles.newtask__content}>
        <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
          <TextInputField
            name="task_name"
            placeholder="Task Name ..."
            onChange={inputsChangedHandler}
          ></TextInputField>
          <TextArea
            onChange={inputsChangedHandler}
            placeholder="Task Description ..."
          ></TextArea>
          <SelectGroup
            onChange={inputsChangedHandler}
            name="task_priority"
            options={["low", "medium", "urgent", "backlog"]}
            default="Priority"
          />
          <SelectGroup
            onChange={inputsChangedHandler}
            name="task_type"
            options={["action", "research", "chore"]}
            default="Type"
          ></SelectGroup>
          <Submit name="Send"></Submit>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewTask;
```

I'm getting Property 'task' does not exist on type '{ taskName: string; taskType: string; taskPriority: string;
taskDescription: string; taskStatus: string; }'.  TS2339

So my questions are as follows:

- What is missing here?
- What has to be done to resolve it
- What ts-mechanism lies behind that error, so i can understand it properly

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Line 18, change:

```js
  const [task, setTask] = useState({
    taskName: "",
    taskType: "",
    taskPriority: "",
    taskDescription: "",
    taskStatus: "new",
  });
```

To

```js
  const [task, setTask] = useState<Properties>({
    taskName: "",
    taskType: "",
    taskPriority: "",
    taskDescription: "",
    taskStatus: "new",
  });
```

Or, even better yet, in the object literal, include a `task` field.

```js
  const [task, setTask] = useState<Properties>({
    taskName: "",
    taskType: "",
    taskPriority: "",
    taskDescription: "",
    taskStatus: "new",
    task: [],
  });
```

The `useState` function is a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). TypeScript often resorts to type inference, if things are not explicit. Which is not a bad thing. In fact, it's what makes TypeScript so much more elegant to write, than languages like Java, C# (at least older versions of C#), C++ (at least older versions of C++).

The thing about generic functions is that if a function accepts a particular value of the type outlined in the generic parameter, and a parameter was not explicitly provided, then it will infer what type the function parameter would be.

For example, here is a generic function.

```js
function identity<T>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}
```

In other languages (such as Java), in order to invoke `identity`, you have to absolutely provide what type the function must accept. But in TypeScript both of the following invocations are correct:

```js
const value1 = identity(10); // Will return a value of type number
const value2 = identity<number>(10); // Same idea
```

But, the importance of generics is that you can be more explicit in what can be accepted by a function.

For example:

```js
// We want a number

const value = identity('10'); // Will get you a string; not number
const value = identity<number>('10'); // TypeScript will refuse to compile
```

Sometimes, you want to be explicit.

In your example the `Properties` type has an optional `task` field. But, when you invoked `useState` using that object literal with the `task` field missing, TypeScript inferred that the `task` field is not at all a part of the expected type.

Here's what things look like with the `identity` function:

```
const obj = identity({
  taskName: "",
  taskType: "",
  taskPriority: "",
  taskDescription: "",
  taskStatus: "new",
});

// The type of `obj` will be pretty much the above object, but with
// the `task` field missing.

obj.task = []; // Compiler error!
```

To prevent the compiler error, you can do this instead:

```
const obj = identity<Properties>({
  taskName: "",
  taskType: "",
  taskPriority: "",
  taskDescription: "",
  taskStatus: "new",
});

obj.task = []; // This is fine
```

Answer (score 0):

*emphasized text*When you assign an object to a state variable in React (and don't use a generic, i.e. `useState<Properties>`, Typescript will assume you want to use that type for the state and enforce it throughout the rest of your code. Your state object initially looks like this:

```
{
    taskName: "",
    taskType: "",
    taskPriority: "",
    taskDescription: "",
    taskStatus: "new",
  }
```

but later on you try and set the state:

```
setTask((prevState) => ({
      task: {
        ...prevState.task,
        [name]: value,
      },
    }));
```

There is no "task" property of your state object, it should just read

```
setTask((prevState) => ({
      task: {
        ...prevState,
        [name]: value,
      },
    }));
```

You'll also have a problem I think indexing using `name` because your HTML names don't match up with the type names, but hopefully this gets you on the path to understanding how TS expects your state to look.